# web api 2 file upload error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using this code to process a file upload to a web api:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string provider)
{  
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        throw new Exception();

    var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider); // FAILS HERE
    foreach (var file in streamProvider.Contents)
    {
        var imageFilename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
        var imageStream = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    }
}
```

but it throws an error here: `await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);`

The error is: Error reading MIME multipart body part.
The inner Exception is:

```
{"Cannot access a disposed object."}
```

any ideas on why this error is coming up?

Comment: better add try catch blocks

Comment: @user3629247 He has the exception already why would he need a trycatch? he wouldnt be posting here if he was ignoring the problem

Comment: @user441365 are you using the right Content-Type header value?? aka Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: if we wrap our method in try-catch block,we can gracefully handle any errors that occur as part of the method. for this scenario he already catch the exception

Comment: Are you using the [`enctype`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string provider)
{  
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        throw new Exception();

    var streamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(); // HERE
    foreach (var file in streamProvider.Contents)
    {
        var imageFilename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
        var imageStream = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
}
```

It looks as it should be called like this.

Comment: If I copy this code exactly, I get the disposed error right on the line with the `// HERE` comment :/

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem but the provided solution did not work for me, so here is mine : the file you have uploaded did not match the security limits of IIS.

http://forums.asp.net/t/2062896.aspx?Error+reading+MIME+multipart+body+part+when+upload+image

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30000000" /> <!-- if you forget this one it does not work -->
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exception, but for a different reason.  My Post method had a return type of void.  Once I changed the return type to `Task<[T]>`, type of string in my case, it started working.

Comment: This is the common .NET "async void" problem (i.e you can not have an async method to return void) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have path to store uploaded files. Something like this:

```
var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider(@"C:\Uploads");
```